# R: reshape data by chunks - more elegant way

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I stumble upon the following thing. I read the reshape manual, but still lost.
Is there an efficient and more elegant way to reshape the matrix of even chunks? 
the code to generate the matrix and reshaped matrix is below.

```
# current matrix
x <- matrix(sample(20*9), 20, 9)
colnames(x) <- c(paste("time",c(1:3),sep="_"),
paste("SGNL", 1, c(1:3), sep="_"),
paste("SGNL", 2, c(1:3), sep="_"))
# reshaped matrix
x.reshaped <- rbind( x[,c(1,4,7)], x[,c(2,5,8)], x[,c(3,6,9)] )
colnames(x.reshaped) <- sub("\\_1$", "", colnames(x.reshaped))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide links to and acknowledgement of sources you use.

Comment: similar to @akrun's answer `sapply(1:3, function(ii) x[, grep(paste0(ii, '$'), colnames(x))])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create the subset of matrices (based on the index generated by the `seq`) in a `list` and then `rbind` it together.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:3, function(i) x[,seq(i, length.out=3, by=3)]))
```

Or using a `for` loop

```
 m2 <- c()
 for(i in 1:3) { m2 <- rbind(m2, x[,seq(i, length.out=3, by=3)])}
```

Comment: strange! but for the real set I have the following error Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Comment: @JohnAmraph `rbind` requires the column names to be matched.  Perhaps in the original dataset you don't have matching names.  One way would be `colnames(x) <- NULL` and then try with the code.

Comment: @JohnAmraph In your example too, the column names are not matching and it is working.  Do you really have a `matrix` as input?

Comment: @JohnAmraph THe reason I asked about whether it is `matrix` or not is `x <- as.data.frame(x)` and then run the code.  I get the same error.  I would say convert the `data.frame` (if it is your original data) to `matrix` (`x1 <- as.matrix(x)` and then run the code.

Comment: yep, matrix was an issue

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an approach that is name-based and not position-based, then you should look at `melt` from "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
melt(as.data.table(x), measure.vars = patterns("time", "SGNL_1", "SGNL_2"))
```

Example output:

```
head(melt(as.data.table(x), measure.vars = patterns("time", "SGNL_1", "SGNL_2")))
#    variable value1 value2 value3
# 1:        1     48    110    155
# 2:        1     67     35    140
# 3:        1    102     55     72
# 4:        1    161     39     66
# 5:        1     36    137     99
# 6:        1    158    169     85
```

---

Or, in base R:

```
patts <- c("time", "SGNL_1", "SGNL_2")
sapply(patts, function(y) c(x[, grep(y, colnames(x))]))
#       time SGNL_1 SGNL_2
#  [1,]   48    110    155
#  [2,]   67     35    140
#  [3,]  102     55     72
#  [4,]  161     39     66
#  [5,]   36    137     99
# .
# .
# .
# .
# [56,]   13      1     84
# [57,]   40     46     95
# [58,]  152      7    178
# [59,]   81     79    123
# [60,]   50    101    146
```

---

Data generated with `set.seed(1)`.

Comment: Or perhaps: `patts <-   unique(sub("(.*)_.*", "\\1", colnames(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
x[,c(matrix(1:9, 3, byrow=TRUE))] # or shorter:
x[,matrix(1:9, 3, byrow=TRUE)]
```